# Question caused by lambda expression in python?

Tags: python, function, lambda, reference

I wrote a Python code like:

```py
fun_list = []
for i in range(10):
    fun_list.append(lambda : f(i))
for j in range(10):
    fun_list[j]()
```

I want it to output numbers from 0 to 9, but actually it outputs 9 for ten times!

I think the question is that the variable is be transported into function f only it was be called. Once it was be called it will globally find variable named 'i'.

How to modify the code so that it can output numbers from 0 to 9?

Comment: why use `lambda` ? just `fun_list.append(i)` can be output from 0 to 9.

Comment: That's due to lambda's late bindings. I'm sure there's a dupe on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code doesn't make sense`fun_list[j]()` how are you calling a List Element?

If You Want to append the numbers mentioned above into your array then Correct Code is:-

```
fun_list = []
for i in range(10): ### the range has to be from 0 to 10 that is [0,10)
    fun_list.append(i) ### You dont need lambda function to append i
```

What This does is also if of No need because you first of all havent initialized what is f?... Is it a function?. You here are not appending the value but instead appending the called function statement. You dont need that. Just do it simply like above....:-

```
fun_list.append(lambda : f(i))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My very first question is that I need to use schedule module to implement an alert. The alert config was been read in a json file and there are many alert content and alert time, so I use for loop to add them into schedule.

I add the very first code! Thank you!